# Bounded weak and weak-$\star$ topologies and metrics

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a reflexive and separable Banach space. Let $(h_n)$ be a sequence dense in $\overline{B^*_1}$ (the closed ball in $X^*$ of radius $1$). Set
$$
d(x,y) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |(x-y, h_n)|,
$$
where $(x-y, h_n)=(x-y, h_n)_{X,X^*}$ is the dual pairing on $X$.
Then $d$ is symmetric, satisfies the triangle inequality and $d(x,y) = 0 \implies x = y$, hence $d$ is a metric.

On closed bounded (by the norm) balls of $X$, the metric $d$ induces the weak topology.

Can the topology induced by $d$ be described in a functional way in relation to the weak topology or the bounded weak-topology? Would any answer change if $d$ is defined using the ratio $\frac{|(x-y,h_n)|}{1 + |(x-y,h_n)|}$ ?

This seems to be something that should be in Megginson's book on Banach spaces, I can only see something related in exercise 2.86-88 of section 2.7.

Comment: For $E$ a Banach space, the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology on $E^*$ is not metrizable unless $E$ is finite-dimensional. The reason is that a base of neighbourhoods of $0$ in $E^*$ is defined by the polars of the norm-compact absolutely convex subsets of $E$. If the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology is first-countable, then this implies that there are countably many norm-compact absolutely convex sets covering $E$. By the Baire category theorem, this means one of them has nonempty interior, so $E$ is locally compact and therefore finite-dimensional.

Comment: I've not read the book, but I bet Megginson is using "complete" in the sense of uniform spaces, not metric spaces (because that makes it a true statement). If $E$ is a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space, then both the weak-$\ast$ and the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology restrict to the same, *metrizable*, topology on any bounded subset of $E^*$, but are not metrizable themselves.

Comment: @RobertFurber Megginson has in Definition 2.3.1 the following: "A topological space is topologically complete if some complete metric induces its topology."

Comment: @RobertFurber what exactly do you mean by "the polars of the norm-compact absolutely convex subsets of $E^\star$"?

Comment: I commented because I don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment, unfortunately. I will see if I can look at what the Megginson book says (I take it that it is *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*?). The polar of a subset $S \subseteq E$ is the set of elements of $E^*$ that are bounded above by $1$ on $S$ (some authors define it slightly differently).

Comment: Proving that the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology is not *completely* metrizable is easier, actually. By Banach-Alaoğlu the closed ball of radius $n$ in $E^*$ is compact, $E^*$ is the union of these closed balls, so by the Baire category theorem if $E^*$ is completely metrizable in the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology then one of these balls has nonempty interior, so $E^*$ is locally compact and therefore finite-dimensional.

Comment: Megginson does not say that the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology on $E^*$ is topologically complete, he says it is complete (meaning in the sense of uniform spaces, see Definition 2.1.48). This is true (so I win the bet I made earlier). As I have mentioned, the bounded weak-$\ast$ topology it is not metrizable unless $E^*$, and therefore $E$, is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @RobertFurber Thank you for helping to clarify this! You are right, "complete" is different to "topologically complete", it now makes sense. I removed the reference to completeness from the question. I still have my original question though, how does the topology induced by $d$ looks in relation to the weak, bounded weak and norm topologies?